# Vue.js Router: Run code when component is ready

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a single-page app with Vue.js and its official router.

I have a menu and a component (.vue file) per every section which I load using the router. In every component I have some code similar to this:

```
<template>
    <div> <!-- MY DOM --> </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {},
        methods: {},
        route: {
            activate() {},
        },
        ready: function(){}
    }
</script>
```

I want to execute a piece of code (init a jQuery plugin) once a component has finished transitioning in. If I add my code in the `ready` event, it gets fired only the first time the component is loaded. If I add my code in the `route.activate` it runs every time, which is good, but the DOM is not loaded yet, so is not possible to init my jQuery plugin.

How can I run my code every time a component has finished transitioning in and its DOM is ready?

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Vue.js Router, it means that each time you will transition to a new route, Vue.js will need to update the DOM. And by default, Vue.js performs DOM updates asynchronously.

In order to wait until Vue.js has finished updating the DOM, you can use Vue.nextTick(callback). The callback will be called after the DOM has been updated.

In your case, you can try:

```
route: {
    activate() {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            // => 'DOM loaded and ready'
        })
    }
}
```

For further information:

- https://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-nextTick
- https://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue

Comment: The problem is the ready method only runs the 1st time the component is loaded, but if I go to another route, then I come back to this one, the ready method wont run. I need it to run every time the route gets called.

Comment: I'm trying to access an element $('.test'), which exists on the component dom from the nextTick call back and I can't get it. It works with a setTimeout though, so seems like the dom hasnt been loaded yet

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
mounted(){
  // jquery code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this may be a bit late... If I guess correctly, the component having problem stays on the page when you navigate between routes. This way, Vue reuses the component, changing what's inside it that needs to change, rather than destroy and recreate it. Vue provides a `key` attribute to `Properly trigger lifecycle hooks of a component`. By changing a component's `key`, we can indicate Vue to rerender it. See [key in guide](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#key) for details and [key in api](http://vuejs.org/api/#key) for code sample.